# android read textfile from web

Tags: java, android, onedrive

Im attempting to read a text file from my *onedrive*, I need to check the version of the database and update if necessary.

This is an example of my code:

```
 private void checkVersion() {

    try {

        int dbversion = prefs.getInt("dbversion", 1);
        int dblastversion;


        URL url = new URL("");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;

        str = in.readLine();

        in.close();

        System.out.println(str);

        dblastversion = Integer.valueOf(str);

        if (dbversion < dblastversion)
            System.out.println("updates available");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app crash and I got this error from logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ex.example/com.ex.example.ActMenu}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

On this line

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Somebody know what is the problem? Or its better use another cloud to stor the textfile. Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok as GPRathour said I updated my code to this:

```
class Getversion_Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        System.out.println("starting");
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=b9186f8cb138a030!56556&authkey=!AFmrzOGv_OMArzo&ithint=file%2ctxt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;

            str = in.readLine();

            in.close();

            System.out.println(str);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

         System.out.println("ended");

    }
}
```

And I call in th onCreate like this to test:

```
 new Getversion_Async().execute();
```

Ok this code runs fine I use a site to host the file and the link ends with `.txt` and works fine but I cant edit the file. Somebody know how I can do this with onedrive?

Comment: Don't use System.out.println(), use Log.d("value", "ended");

Comment: I edited the question agaig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception clearly says `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. To read file from server you need to perform some Network operation and it is not a good practice to perform it on `Main Thread / UI Thread` as it will hang the UI till the operation is performed.

What you need to do is, run this in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
class LogoutUser_Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            // Do your network task here

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

            // Process the result

        }
}
```

Comment: The only way its to use `Async Tank`?

Comment: @Azazel What you need to do is, perform your network operation on a separate thread. May be it could work by making simple threads also. But better way will be to create an `AsycnTask` I think.